# Russian characters in equations without \textup in XeLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, xetex, pdftex, russian

I want to change LaTeX engine from `PdfLaTeX` to `XeLaTeX`. 
There are a lot of formulas and equations with Russian text inside. And it used without any commands.

MWE for pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtext} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 

\begin{document}

    Формула: $F_{подпись} = Ф$

    Уравнение:
    \begin{equation}
    X_{первый} = Y_{второй}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I tried the same example with XeLaTeX. There is no errors, but Russian characters are displayed only with `\textup` command, like it was said in this answer:[Cyrillic symbols in math equation xetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59181/cyrillic-symbols-in-math-equation-xetex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}  
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}  
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif} 
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}

    Формула: $F_{подпись} = Ф$

    Уравнение:
    \begin{equation}
    X_{первый} = Y_{\textup{второй}}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Are there any ways to do it without `\textup`?

Comment: I'm assuming `первый` is a named index, in which case is always should be typeset in the upright text font so it is not confused with `п*е*р*в*ы*й` or six separate indices.

Comment: @daleif Yes, it is index, but it should be written like a whole word.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201239/cant-get-unicode-symbols-in-math-mode solve your problem?

Comment: @JPi Yes, it is!

Comment: Which is why you mark it with textup, whole word in the upright text font. We have to do the same in Latin based scripts

Comment: @daleif It was just an example, which shows that Russain text in math mode is not displayed without  `\textup`, but displayed with it.